# In a 5 day weather array how does one isolate a single time slot per day using swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to get just the high temp, day icon etc for the peak of the day, which would be noon. I think this is done through the DateFormatter, here is what I have so far and it is returning the 5 day forecast no problem, but it updates every 3 hours. Is there anyway to disable this and/or just make a call for just 12:00 noon using this code?

```
func getDayOfWeek(today:String)->String? {
    let formatter  = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let todayDate = formatter.date(from: today)
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE" // "eeee" -> Friday
    let weekDay = formatter.string(from: todayDate!)

    return weekDay
}
```

All the weather data:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0054,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [{
                "dt": 1525100400,
                "main": {
                    "temp": 12.43,
                    "temp_min": 10.44,
                    "temp_max": 12.43,
                    "pressure": 1015.9,
                    "sea_level": 1035.33,
                    "grnd_level": 1015.9,
                    "humidity": 64,
                    "temp_kf": 1.99
                },
                "weather": [{
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }],
                "clouds": {
                    "all": 0
                },
                "wind": {
                    "speed": 4.66,
                    "deg": 307.008
                },
                "sys": {
                    "pod": "d"
                },
                "dt_txt": "2018-04-30 15:00:00"
            }
```

Comment: How do you receive the data for temperature on any one day? Is it blocked into hour? Are you able to show a sample JSON response?

Comment: what does a date formatter have to do with weather?

Comment: @Super_Simon here it is, it updates every 3 hours, at my time 9:00am it just moved to 15:00:00, I would like to lock in the time at 12:00:00 for every day in the 5 day and stop the updates until the next is added.

Comment: @RichJ Please [edit] your question with all relevant details. Do not post this information in comments.

Comment: @Clashsoft - I was hoping to lock in that single time slot daily, would I do a separate formatter.time code line?

Comment: @Super_Simon here is a samples "dt_txt":"2018-04-30 15:00:00"

Comment: @Rich J, unfortunately your code has disappeared. Can you edit your question and include it in there?

Comment: To me it looks more like the date (dt and dt_txt) are timestamps for when the report was produced rather that for what time the forecast  is

Comment: I recommend to use `Decodable` to parse the JSON into structs and decode the UNIX timestamps into `Date`. That makes it much easier to filter the dates. But consider that all dates are in UTC so in your timezone there might not be an exact noon date.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, That report updates every 3 hours and when it does it change all the data to that new time stamp, So if the temp drops, if the icon changes to a night icon etc., it will pick that up and update the App. So, being able to lock that time in at 12:00:00 daily would just give the viewer just the high temp, noon icon etc for each of the 5 days. Just like what you see in any long range weather forecast.

Comment: @vadian There is an exact 12:00:00 and it happens at 6:00am my time, can my code be altered to reflect this and lock it in?

Comment: But doesn't that mean that the data you need will only be available for an 3 hour timespan? If that is the case then just go with the latest forecast.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned if the dates are in `Date` format it's quite easy to filter them

Comment: Can you alter my code to lock in that 12:00:00 daily time stamp?

Comment: Once again, you have to convert the UNIX timestamps (`1525100400`) to `Date` (preferable parse the JSON into structs with `Decodable`). Your code is useless for filtering.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not if you can just pick that time slot only and disregard the future updates, until it comes around the next day, and as mentioned when it updates it give you the forecast for that 3 hour period, which is confusing for a long range forecast.

Comment: @vadian Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ok, but you don't need any date formatter for this, just check if the value for "dt" starts with 12 or if the value for dt_txt contains "12:00:00"

Comment: Yes I get that, but how would the code look to just pick that time slot?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean now, are you saying there are several time slots in one response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **very** simple example as starting point showing only the relevant data.

The example decodes the `list` array into a custom struct. the `dt` key is decoded into `Date`. Then it creates a `DateComponents` instance with noon in the current time zone and filters the dates.

```
struct WeatherData : Decodable {
    let cod : String
    let list : [List]
}

struct List : Decodable {
    let dt : Date
}
```

---

```
let jsonString = """
{ "cod": "200", "message": 0.0054, "cnt": 40, "list": [{ "dt": 1525100400, "main": {"temp": 12.43, "temp_min": 10.44, "temp_max": 12.43, "pressure": 1015.9, "sea_level": 1035.33, grnd_level": 1015.9, "humidity": 64, "temp_kf": 1.99 }, "weather": [{"id": 800, "main": "Clear", "description": "clear sky", "icon": "01d"}],    "clouds": {"all": 0}, "wind": {"speed": 4.66, "deg": 307.008},"sys": {"pod": "d"},"dt_txt": "2018-04-30 15:00:00"}]}
"""
```

---

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    let result = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
    let utcDifference = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT() / 3600
    let noonComponents = DateComponents(hour: 12 + utcDifference, minute: 0, second: 0)
    let noonDates = result.list.filter { Calendar.current.date($0.dt, matchesComponents:noonComponents) }
    print(noonDates)

} catch {
    print("error:", error)
}
```

Comment: Can this work for JsonObj also? My whole app is on Json not Decodable? What would I have to change to make it work?

Comment: I recommend to learn how to use `Decodable`. It's much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the field dt and/or the field dt_txt as string values and perform simple string comparison to see if this is the noon forecast.

```
dt.starts(with: "12")
//or
dt_txt.contains("12:00:00")
```

Comment: This cannot work. `dt` is an UNIX timestamp, an integer, and `dt_txt` is the (unique) calculation date

Comment: Why not, this issue is not about the correct time or time formatting it is about matching a string that identifies a specific json response. Why overcomplicate things?

Comment: Because `dt` is **not** a string and `dt_txt` is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, but dt can easily be converted to an string or can be easily compared to integer values instead. As I understand it there are forecasts published around 9:00, 12:00, 12:00 etc and dt_txt clearly identifies which forecast it is.