# How to take only specific values from JSON? Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift

I was making a weather app that can display temperatures in "day" and "night".
To do so, I need to take data from an API given below.

[here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=42.874722&lon=74.612222&APPID=079587841f01c6b277a82c1c7788a6c3)

**If you have checked out that, the problem is I need to take only temperatures from times "3:00 AM" and "15:00"/"3:00 PM" ignoring other times and temperatures. Then I have to display it on my UICollectionView (will do it by myself)**

I know it may be done using DateFormatter and taking a value from "dt" or "dt_txt". However, I really need to know how it can be done. The source will be attached. Any help will be appreciated. Any errors you notice besides my problem, will be appreciated as well. :]

ViewController: **NOTE: please see only UICollectionView functions, I added others just for referance**

```
class SecondTaskVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var weatherModel: WeatherModelDecodable?
    let weatherMmodel = [WeatherModelDecodable]()
    var listModel = [ListDecodable]()

    let textArray = ["понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота", "воскресенье"]


    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var descrpLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


    }

    // UICollectionView

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WeatherCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WeatherCollectionViewCell

        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=42.874722&lon=74.612222&APPID=079587841f01c6b277a82c1c7788a6c3"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON { (response) in
            let result = response.data
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.weatherModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherModelDecodable.self, from: result!)
                if let tempToConvert = self.weatherModel?.list[indexPath.row].main.temp{

                    // CHECK THIS, I KNOW IT IS NOT CORRECT, BUT YOU GET ME.
                    if let timeResult = (self.weatherModel?.list[indexPath.row].dt) {
                        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
                        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

                        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timeResult))
                        if dateFormatter.string(from: date) == "3:00 AM"{
                            cell.dayTemp.text = String(format: "%.0f", tempToConvert - 273.15) + "°C"
                            self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", tempToConvert - 273.15) + "°C"
                    }
                        if dateFormatter.string(from: date) == "3:00 PM"{
                            cell.dayTemp.text = "4 c"
                            //self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", tempToConvert - 273.15) + "°C"
                        }
                    }
                    ///////
                }
                self.cityLabel.text = self.weatherModel?.city.name
                self.dateLabel.text = self.weatherModel?.list[indexPath.row].dtTxt

                // displaying date and the week
            if  let dateResult = (self.weatherModel?.list[indexPath.row].dt) {
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dateResult))
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium //Set time style
                dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium //Set date style
                let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                let str = localDate.components(separatedBy: " 2018")
                let dd = localDate.replacingOccurrences(of: str[0], with: self.textArray[indexPath.row])
                let stringg = dd.components(separatedBy: " ")
                cell.dayCollection.text = stringg[0]
                print(stringg[0])
            }
        }catch let error{
            print("error in decoding",error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
 }
```

Data Model: **In case it is important**

```
struct WeatherModelDecodable: Codable {
    let list: [ListDecodable]
    let city: CityDecodable
    enum CodinKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case list = "list"
        case city = "city"
    }
}

struct CityDecodable: Codable {
    let name: String
}
struct ListDecodable: Codable {
    let dt: Int
    let main: MainClassDecodable
    let weather: [WeatherDecodable]
    let wind: WindDecodable
    let dtTxt: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
    case dt = "dt"
    case main = "main"
    case weather = "weather"
    case wind = "wind"
    case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
}

 }
struct MainClassDecodable: Codable {
     let temp: Double
     let tempMin: Double
     let tempMax: Double
     let pressure: Double
     let humidity: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case temp = "temp"
    case tempMin = "temp_min"
    case tempMax = "temp_max"
    case pressure = "pressure"
    case humidity = "humidity"
    }
}
struct WeatherDecodable: Codable {
     let main: String
     let description: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case main = "main"
    case description = "description"
}
}
struct WindDecodable: Codable {
     let speed: Double
     let deg: Double
}
```

If you need anything that would help me solve this, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Unrelated but **do not** put the code to retrieve the weather data in `cellForItemAt`. That's the wrong place. Put it in the **controller** (`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`), then populate the **model** (data source array) and reload the collection **view**. `cellForItemAt` is only for assigning the data from the **model** to the **view** (the cell)

Comment: Thanks, I will do that! Do you have any ideas for my problem? @vadian

Comment: Your link doesn't work, I assume it contains an API-key or similar.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it works now. Please check that out

Comment: You might want to remove your API ID from the URL. Instead, show us a part of your JSON. Apply the filter on `list` of `WeatherModelDecodable`, or if you don't want them at all, you want want to use a custom init for `WeatherModelDecodable`, and there add it or not to `list`.

Comment: @Larme I didn't get you. Please could you provide a broader example?

Comment: This looks like a question you've [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772700/how-to-access-enum-within-struct-model-swift) and it's also very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100718/in-a-5-day-weather-array-how-does-one-isolate-a-single-time-slot-per-day-using-s/50103531#50103531). To find more questions like this search for `[swift] dt_txt`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for that. But actually, the current question is more different. I used a .json file in the previous question, this time I use an external API. Plus I use here  a `UICollectionView`. Any ideas to my current problem?

Comment: I have posted an answer but I fail to see how file vs API and your type of view is relevant.

Comment: @vadian Hello, I just want to ask how do I do this? "Put it in the controller (`viewDidLoad ` or `viewWillAppear`), then populate the model (data source array) and reload the `collection view` ." I tried creating a new function and call it in my `cellForItemAt` but it doesn't work. Please could you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all if you insert `&units=metric` into the URL query you get the degrees in `°C` (no conversion needed).
- Second of all if you use the *date decoding strategy* `.secondsSince1970` you can decode `dt` as `Date` (no conversion needed).
- Third of all if you use the *key decoding strategy* `.convertFromSnakeCase` you can omit all CodingKeys.

---

This is a simplified version of your structs omitting the redundant occurrences of `Decodable` in the names, `dt` will be decoded as `Date`

```
struct WeatherModel : Decodable {
    let cod : String
    let list : [List]
}

struct List : Decodable {
    let weather : [Weather]
    let main : Main
    let dt : Date
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    let main : String
    let description : String
}

struct Main: Decodable {
    let temp : Double
    let tempMin : Double
    let tempMax : Double
    let pressure : Double
    let humidity : Int
}
```

Decode the JSON with the mentioned *strategies*

```
do {
     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
     decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
     self.weatherModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherModel.self, from: result!)
```

To filter the 3AM / 3PM dates you need first the difference from your local time to UTC

```
     let utcDifference = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT() / 3600
```

Now filter the `list` array

```
     let threeAMPMForecast = self.weatherModel.list.filter{
         let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: $0.dt)
         return hour == (3 + utcDifference) || hour == (15 + utcDifference)
     }
     print(threeAMPMForecast)
     // or to print all temperatures
     print(threeAMPMForecast.map{ $0.main.temp }) 

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Please try the code in a Playground.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is the filtering the `list` array code you provided the same as getting the temperatures only at 3 am and 3 pm ? The thing is, I need to display to of them in different `tempLabel` s.

Comment: Yes, the filtered list contains all available forecasts at 3 AM and 3 PM. But you can change the code to use two separate filters

Comment: "To filter the 3AM / 3PM dates you need first the difference from your local time to UTC" - I didn't really understand this. Please could you provide broader explanation?

Comment: The OpenWeatherMap dates are in the UTC timezone. To match the three hour interval you have to convert your local time zone to UTC.